# Accessing Axios error codes in interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) response interceptors in client-side JavaScript/React/etc, how can I access error codes such as the following:

- `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` (API server is down)
- `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` (local network is down)

I noticed that these codes get printed to the console by `axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js`, but I can't seem to work out how to access them myself in my response interceptor?

Code:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {

    console.log(error.???);

    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

NB: The point is to be able to distinguish between "Your internet is down" and "Our API is down" when showing an error message to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can get status like this `error.response.status` but write safe code since it is not always true. In case of 502, error.response is undefined and will break

Here is how you can handle your errors

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
  if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
    if (error?.response?.status') === 504) {
      throw {
        message: 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.',
      };
    } else {
      throw {
        message: 'You are not connected to the internet. Verify your connection and then try again.',
      };
    }
  }
  if (error.response) {
    if (error.response.status === 500) {
      throw {
        message: 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.',
      };
    }
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // logout logic
    }
    if (error.response.status === 403) {
      // redirect user to some home page since that action is not allowed
    }
    throw { ...error.response.data, statusCode: error.response.status };
  }
  throw {
    message: 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.',
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid this does not answer the question. I would like to read the `ERR_` codes as explained. With your code, it prints "You are not connected to the internet. Verify your connection and then try again.", even if I am connected and the API is down. I would like to be able to distinguish between "Your internet is down" and "Our API is down" when showing an error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Axios error codes via `error.code` from your interceptors. For example:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {

    console.log(error.code);

    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

The possible error codes defined by axios can be found in their [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios?tab=readme-ov-file#error-types).

You mentioned:

> NB: The point is to be able to distinguish between "Your internet is down" and "Our API is down" when showing an error message to the user.

This may be impossible to achieve since axios is not be able to distinguish when "your internet is down"(*no internet connection*) or "API is down"(*Bad DNS*). Axios will report a generalized *"Network_Error"*.

This is not an issue with axios, but the underlying [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). For security reasons details about the network error is not exposed to JS. You can find out for yourself with the barebones XMLHttpRequest like so:

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onerror = (e) => console.log("There is not much network info here", e, xhr)
xhr.open("GET", "https://zacky.web.app")
xhr.send()
```